# Rails using media queries?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I want to transform my application into a responsive application

I want to have to different css files. one for desktop and one for all others.

How can I set the mediaquiers?

Normaly I do somthing like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 990px)"
```

But how can I integate this in :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'xyz', 'bootstrap.min', 'styled_button', :cache => "_xyz" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be through css blocks . For example -

```
    body{
    //GLOBAL STYLES

    @media only screen and (max-width: 770px){
        //MOBILE ONLY STYLES
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:771px) and (max-width:1040px){
        //TABLET ONLY STYLES
    }


    }
```

Comment: yes of course but I have always to wait some time until I can check the answer :) didn't forgott it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'xyz', 'bootstrap.min', 'styled_button', :cache => "_xyz",  :media => "only screen and (max-width: 990px)" %>
```